# `-ms-touch-action` style don't get applied with $.css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to apply the CSS property `ms-touch-action` without success by using the [$.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```
$('#demo').css({
    'height': '100%',
    'position': 'relative',

    '-ms-touch-action': 'none'
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqc2r/)

Comment: And on which browser are you trying it? Tested on ms browsers (IE) and it works as expected

Comment: Shouldn't it be applied in all of them anyway? As when using an style sheet that you can inspect it anyways? (Chrome, Firefox, IE 9)

Comment: It **only** works in IE10 as far as I know ?

Comment: No, only valid properties are added using `.css()`

Comment: Will it be applied in IE 10 correctly then?

Comment: @Alvaro please test it on your side, thank you...

Comment: @A.Wolff I have no access to IE 10...

Comment: http://realworldvalidator.com/css/module/Microsoft/-ms-touch-action

Comment: @sudhar I know it, But when using css style sheets you can visualize it in any browser.

Comment: @Alvaro BUT what could be the goal to see non valid CSS property here? Maybe you should tell us instead what are you looking for, looks like an XY problem

Comment: @A.Wolff nobody has yet confirmed me that it works on IE 10. I wondering if the css method won't add it either in IE 10.

Comment: @Alvaro It will add it in IE10/11, not sure even still prefixed in IE11

Comment: @A.Wolff - The prefixed version was removed in IE11, so it only works in IE10.

Comment: @adeneo Thaks for useful info as usual

Comment: @adeneo it is being applied in IE 11 as well. I've just tested it.

Comment: The docs says IE11 uses the non-prefixed `touch-action`, but they probably kept support for the prefixed version as well.

Comment: @Alvaro I must be missing something: "I have no access to IE 10" ... "it is being applied in IE 11 as well. I've just tested it" ?????? What about emulation support?!

Comment: @A.Wolff - doesn't know how the emulator works ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I've just realized I had 8 more trial minutes in browserstack :)

Comment: @Alvaro you'd have better to realize you can emulate older IE mode in IE11, press F12 and check relevant tab (last one) ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff I was using IE 11 and IE 10 on browserstack, at my developing environment I only have IE 9.

Comment: @Alvaro Time to upgrade IE then. FYI, `css()` add vendor prefix, you should then use to support IE10/11: `'touch-action': 'none'`, this will become: `-ms-touch-action` on IE10

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
var elem = document.getElementById("demo");
elem.setAttribute("style","position:relative;-ms-touch-action:none;height: 100%,");
$('body').append($('#demo').attr('style'));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqc2r/1/)

Comment: That works, but then again it doesn't really work as now you're just bypassing `element.style.msTouchAction` to insert a string with a CSS property that doesn't exists ?

Comment: @adeneo OP asked to apply the css to that element so i tried this way it will set